# Record h.264 video in Flash without streaming server?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Is it at all possible to save h.264 video from the Flash/Actionscript Camera (i.e. webcam) without needing a streaming server (like fms/wowza/red5)?

Where I'm also going with this is, I'd like to take the sampleData from Microphone, and transcode it client-side so that a user can record h.264/aac (or mp3) and store it locally or remotely for easy viewing in a mp4 container....

Any tips before I re-invent the wheel or run into a roadblock?

Comment: Also- just to point out, currently the transcoding of audio is needed since Flash only saves compressed audio from microphone as speex, nellymoser, etc... not aac or mp3 :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe made sure that you need a streaming server for the recording.

At least Red5 server is free, and can be installed as part of your Air application.

Web applications will definitely need a streaming server.

Came across something interesting, which you might want to try also:
http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/

It uses an external library.

Comment: But it isn't necessary for audio (i.e. you can access sampledata, as iND pointed out below)... you absolutely sure it's needed for video?

Comment: Only way to get some sort of video streaming, without a streaming server, is to save (like a hack) the frame every 15 seconds as a jpg, and play them back on the other side as sequential jpg's with the audio, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a more free codec that h.264 or mp3 (about licensing with h.264: [ZDnet article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/a-closer-look-at-the-costs-and-fine-print-of-h264-licenses/2884?pg=2)).

That being said, [MicRecording](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858) ([code](http://code.google.com/p/micrecorder/downloads/list)) is an audio recording class that has been developed to save audio to a file.

It uses Adobe's [Microphone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html) class, which has a wealth of examples and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Flash 11 supports recording video in H.264 but not AAC.
So you can record a video with H.264 and Speex.